# AWS SQS queue: The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs

1. Client call a API gateway URL which trigger a lambda function.
2. This lambda read the request body and store it into a SQS queue (Queue1)
3. SQS Queue Queue 1 trigger a lamda function "Second Lamda"
4. Second lambda do some file processing and send message to another Queue "Queue 2"

#1 is working fine but when Second Lambda function trying to create a message in Queue 2 I am getting exception.

Error message is `The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version.: AmazonSQSException` at step 5.

I am using AWS  AWSSDK.SQS 3.7.0.55 in dotnet core.

[image: Steps]

Comment: You might look at this answer once: - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77046729/12326605

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the "Access Policy" of the SQS queue. Even if you have given the required permissions from IAM it won't be enough. You need specifically identify who may access the queue with the "Access Policy" of the queue.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out there was a typo in serverless yml file.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out there was a typo in serverless yml file.